# Regarding uninstalling Linux Mint 17, is deleting the partition will work with no bad effects?

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, linux-mint

Regarding uninstalling Linux Mint 17, is deleting the partition will work with no problem?

I have a dual boot (Windows 8 and Linux Mint 17). When I'm in Windows, I can see from the hard disk management that there is "Unknown Space" I guess, I know it is the Linux Mint. Can I just delete those partitions and have Linux Mint uninstalled, and will it work with no problem?

I want to start over from scratch, will install Windows 8, Linux Mint, Debian. What is the right order if I will do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just delete that partition, you may have some trouble as you will also remove the grub bootloader config (if you are using grub) which could cause the computer not to boot.  But if you are uninstalling everything then reinstalling all at once it wont really be a problem.

Best order for me would be Windows, debian (don't install bootloader) then Mint installing the bootloader, that's if you do it all at once without booting into any OS, otherwise I would do it

Windows - install OS, let it boot into it, just make sure in the partition manager when installing you leave enough free for your linux distro

Debian - Don't Install bootloader - when installing at some point it will ask if you want to install a bootloader/grub, this was on the screen where you did your partitions. just make sure you don't as it will make it easier - then reboot ( it will load windows or nothing), then reboot again into the mint install

Mint - Go through the install (make sure you install on what's left free of the disk) and then in partition manager make sure that a bootloader is checked to install

Comment: Thanks Fegnoid. I want to uninstall all, then start over from scratch, adding one more OS, so 3 OS all-in-all. How to uninstall all please? Currently, I have Windows 8 and Linux Mint 17.

Comment: format the Mint partition in windows, then boot to the windows 8 CD and do a fresh install - remember to do your partitions correct or you wont have enough room for Debian and Mint

Comment: Whenever I went to Windows Hard Disk Management, the only option for the partition of Linux is "DELETE", no other else. And it is labeled as "Unknown Space or something like that", i cant remember. But no option to format it, I think only "DELETE". Will that be okay to delete those partitions (2gb and 15gb)?

Comment: yeah, as long as your booting straight into the windows 8 install it should be fine

Comment: Please explain a bit more, just a newbie here. "Windows, debian (don't install bootloader) then Mint installing the bootloader". I will install Windows 8 from CD, then Debian from usb, then Linux Mint from usb. Will the installer prompt me an option if whether I like to install the bootloader or not. Also, what do you mean "without booting into any OS". After Windows 8, then restart multiple times, then I will shut down, and insert the Debian USB, install, then shut down again after that, finally install Linux Mint usb, right?

Comment: I've edited my answer - this is one of those things where its a bit hard to explain well